# Proper Way to Sanitize Meta Input

Tags: post-meta, validation, sanitization

I have a meta field which gets displaed in the admin panel look like:

```
$field = get_post_meta($postid, 'field_name', true); ?>
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="<?php echo (!empty($field)) ? $field : ''; ?>" />
```

And usually whenever I save these sorts of things I use `sanitize_text_field()` which I thought that was enough, until today... Today I realized that it doesn't properly encode any html entities, such as quotations. For example: Say the user enters into my text field

> Matt said "Jet fuel can't melt steel beams..."

Which can be sanitized using the function above but whenever echo'ed back out to the user I get

> Matt said

The input looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="Matt said " Jet fuel can't melt steel beams" />
```

I can use `htmlspecialchars()` whenever saving my meta but then that defeats the purpose. Why would I ever use `sanitize_text_field()` over `strip_tags( htmlspecialchars() )` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape data while displaying also. Use `esc_attr` in your case. Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="<?php echo (!empty($field)) ? esc_attr( $field ) : ''; ?>" />
```

Check this for full documentation - https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation